# Basic question on tensor product of two vector spaces

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, multilinear-algebra

This may be trivial question, but I am trying to clarify my understanding of this concept.

In the universal property of tensor product of $k$-vector spaces $V$ and $W$, it is stated that

> it is a vector space $L$ with a map $\eta:V\times W\rightarrow L$ such that: given any vector space $U$ and a bilinear map $\phi$ from $V\times W$ into $U$, there is a unique linear map $\phi_1$ from $L$ to $U$ such that $\phi_1\circ \eta=\phi$.

**Q.** I did not see clearly, what $V\times W$ is treated? Is it considered as a set? Or as a vector space? What should we think of $V\times W$ in the definition of universal property? According to this, the map $\eta$ is set map or linear map from $V\times W$ to $L$ (tensor product)?

Comment: It's a cartesian product of vector spaces. In other words, $\phi$ is a function that takes two arguments: one from $V$ and one from $W$, and it is linear in each. Same with $\eta$: it is a bilinear map (although I guess it follows that it is bilinear if you just assume that it is a function, although I think that is not very natural).

Comment: $V \times W$ is not considered to be anything. It's just considered to be the pair of vector spaces - the bilinear map in question takes vectors from $V$ as they first argument and vectors from $W$ as the second argument.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's considered to be a set, named only to define what a bilinear map is as a map of sets. You may find this conceptually unsatisfying, because we seem to have left the category $\text{Vect}$. But this is necessary, because $\text{Vect}$ as a bare category only knows what a linear map is and to define tensor products we need to know what a bilinear map is, so we go back to $\text{Set}$ to talk about those.

(One way to fix this is to think of $\text{Vect}$ not as a category but as a [multicategory](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/multicategory), with multimorphisms given by the multilinear maps.)